# Can I compare 2 iterators pointed to the same container?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have 2 iterators pointed to the same container list. Can I compare them?
I do the following and get error: list iterators incompatible

```
std::list<char>::iterator it=native.begin();
std::advance(it, 3);
std::list<char>::iterator it2=native.begin();
std::advance(it2, 9);
swap(native, it, 3, it2, 7);
.......

void swap(std::list<char> native, 
std::list<char>::iterator place1, 
size_t len1,
std::list<char>::iterator place2, 
size_t len2)
{
std::list<char> swap1, swap2;

std::list<char>::iterator it = native.begin();
while (it != native.end()) {
    if (it == place1) { // here i get error
.......
```

Answer (score 3):

You're passing `native` into `swap` *by value.* That means that `swap` gets its own copy of `native`, while the iterators passed in point into the original one. Hence the incompatibility.

Pass `native` by reference instead:

```
void swap(std::list<char> &native,
  std::list<char>::iterator place1, 
  size_t len1,
  std::list<char>::iterator place2, 
  size_t len2)
```

I don't know the function's semantics; but if it does not modify `native`, then pass it by const reference instead:

```
void swap(const std::list<char> &native,
  std::list<char>::iterator place1, 
  size_t len1,
  std::list<char>::iterator place2, 
  size_t len2)
```